# ReSharper C# naming style for private methods and properties

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper, naming-conventions

I like to make the first letter of private methods, properties and events lowercase and the first letter of public methods, properties and events uppercase. However, in ReSharper 7.1 there is only one option under C# naming style that applies *all* methods, properties and events. What is the best way to tell ReSharper to use a different convention for *private* only?

Comment: Is it not under ResharperOptions=>CodeEditing=>C#=>Naming Style?

Comment: @P_G At least not in v7.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create your own Naming Style Rule.

Resharper Options => Code Editing => [Language] => Naming Style => Advanced Options => +Add...

Verified that the requested functionality is possible using this option.

Comment: Is this possible in JetBrains Rider (Resharper-Based)? Asked in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104681/jetbrains-rider-c-sharp-naming-style-for-private-methods-and-properties

Comment: Do you have an example of what to enter there?